# How can I add time information to STDERR output in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there an easy way to time tag errors going to stderr?  In order to troubleshoot problems, I need to know when an error occurred.

Example:

```
Dec 10 12:00:00 Can't call method "str" on an undefined value
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Define custom handlers for handling warnings and fatal errors:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn sprintf("[%s] ", scalar localtime), @_ };
$SIG{__DIE__}  = sub { die  sprintf("[%s] ", scalar localtime), @_ };

warn;
die;
```

Output:

```
[Fri Dec 11 14:35:37 2009] Warning: something's wrong at c:\temp\foo.pl line 7.
[Fri Dec 11 14:35:37 2009] Died at c:\temp\foo.pl line 8.
```

You might want to use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`.

Comment: This is the quick and dirty solution I was looking for.  Also had to add $SIG{__DIE__} handler to time tag some errors.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...I'm getting two timestamps in the output on dies.
[Thu Dec 10 13:23:51 2009] [Thu Dec 10 13:23:51 2009] blah blah blah

Comment: @macbus: Are you calling `warn` from your `__DIE__` handler? If so, don't. I've updated the answer to include an example.

Comment: @carman: Nope, I've got die in there.  And your examples works so something is wonky on my end.  I am using Exception::Class and Moose so maybe that has something to do with the double time tag?

Comment: Ah...assume (Exception::Class) throw calls die and then in my code, I catch it, print an message, and call die again.  Hence the double time tags.

Answer (score 12):

See [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl).  Way more options about logging than you'll ever need, but at least that's one of the options.

Answer (score 12):

`__WARN__` handlers only catch warnings.  They don't catch `print STDERR`.  If you want to catch everything, you have to tie STDERR.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

package Tie::Handle::Timestamp;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Tie::Handle';

sub stamp {
    return scalar localtime() .": ";
}

sub TIEHANDLE {
    my $class = shift;
    my $handle = shift;

    # Dup the filehandle otherwise we'll be calling ourself
    open my $fh, ">&", $handle or die $!;

    return bless $fh, $class;
}

sub PRINT {
    my $self = shift;
    print { $self } $self->stamp, @_;
}

sub PRINTF {
    my $self = shift;
    my $format = shift;
    printf { $self } $self->stamp . $format, @_;
}

sub CLOSE {
    my $self = shift;
    close $self;
}


package main;

# Tie it at compile time to catch compile time warnings
BEGIN {
    tie *STDERR, "Tie::Handle::Timestamp", *STDERR or die;
}

print STDERR "Foo\n";
warn "Bar";
undef == 2;
```

This has its own perils as you're now relying on how good your tie implementation is.  I'd be surprised there's not already a CPAN module for this, but I don't know of any one I could recommend.

Comment: perhaps there's no cpan module because enough people are happy with CGI::Carp (which timestamps warn & friends but not print STDERR)

Comment: SWATCH BEATS!  SCREW THE SUN!

Answer (score 7):

Create a handler for the `__WARN__` signal and add the date there:

```
use Date::Format;

$SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub { warn time2str( '%C ', time ), $_[0] };

....
# rest of your script here.
```

Comment: Thanks for voting this up! It was completely broken.